# full screen background for empty whitespace around image

Tags: css

I am trying to place an fixed image at center of webpage, I want the remaining space to be filled with background or opacity , But both are not working.

```css
.imagecontainer
{ 
  
  float: left; 
 overflow: auto; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.imagepop {
 
  background: black;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
}

#topright {
  background: silver;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20;
    display: block;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecontainer"><img id="image" src="http://img.cricinfo.com/espncricinfo/Img_nav-div-background.gif" class="imagepop" />
  <a id="topright" href="#" title="TopRight">Close</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but your imagecontianer is 0px height.
Add

```
position: absolute
```

to your image conainer

or easies way:

```
.imagecontainer
{ 
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Why is there unwanted margin if i add it ?

Comment: @Vishnu probably (browser) default margin. Not sure, but adding `margin:0;` to `body` might fix that.